# ros2: embedding a msg as a field in a custom msg

Tags: ros, ros2, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In ROS, I could import other messages using headers.

```
Header header
int32 cout
int32 nch
int32 lenght
```

This way I could include std_msg's **stamp** and **frame_id**.
Other wise, I have to add them manually but I am not sure if this is ideal or not.

```
unit32 seq
builtin_interfaces/Time stamp
string frame_id    
int32 count
int32 nch
int32 lenght
```

I tried using std_msgs/Header header but I received error message.

> Message interface 'std_msgs/Header'
> contains an unknown field type:
> std_msgs/Header header

I added `find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)` to my CMakelist, I am not sure if I am missing anything else

I looked at how other ROS2 msg's used the messages I wanted to use but it seems they are doing it manually as well [link text](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/pendulum_msgs/msg/RttestResults.msg).
I was wondering if it would be okay for me to do this too(writing it manually).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314724/ros2:-embedding-a-msg-as-a-field-in-a-custom-msg/) by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2019-02-05

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-05**:\

> I was wondering if it would be okay for me to do this too(writing it manually).

"manually"?

Are you referring to prefixing the field type with the fully qualified package name that hosts the message?

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-02-05**:
If by prefixing you mean adding the `std_msgs/Header` to my custom message then no.
Doing this will result in an error as pointed in the description. By "manually" I meant coping `std_msgs/Header`  message definition to my custom message. I feel like this is wrong though.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-05**:
No, copying (sub) message types into your own custom message is not needed, and would undermine the entire idea of software reuse (which also applies to message/type definitions).

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-02-05**:
So, that would mean there is a way of importing the message I want to use to the custom message(I am sorry for not using the correct terms) Since I want to add the messages defined in `std_msgs/Header`  to my custom message, is there a line of code I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue I was having was caused by not adding the std_msgs to the dependencies of my CMakelist.

```
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${msg_files}
  DEPENDENCIES builtin_interfaces std_msgs
```

Using `std_msgs/Header` on my custom message's .msg file no longer produces an error.

```
std_msgs/Header header
string frame_id    
int32 count
int32 nch
int32 lenght
```

---

Originally posted by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) with karma: 185 on 2019-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-02-06**:
Although I am able to use the message now, when I try `ros2 topic echo` , the embedded message is not being printed, to be more specific std_msgs/Header header's stamp.  Although I receive no error messages when assigning a value to it when publishing the message, echo will return an empty field.

**Comment by [fiji3119](https://answers.ros.org/users/53083/fiji3119/) on 2020-05-28**:
Just what I was looking for - Thanks! Was having same error.

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2022-03-08**:
I was having the same error. My problem was that in the `.msg` file I had `Header header` instead of `std_msgs/Header header`. After fixing it, my package for the interfaces builds (I am on ROS2 too).

**Comment by [aniltirli](https://answers.ros.org/users/142818/aniltirli/) on 2023-03-24**:
@Obeseturtle Could you figure out "empty field" problem ? I am also not seeing any values under stamp and frame_id.